# Get HTML code of webpage from html page on desktop

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, xmlhttprequest

I'm making an html-file *sample.html* with JavaScript. This file will work on a **local machine** (from desktop) and must get html code from some server (http://ip/login.aspx). Please, help me write the js-code of the function **getHTMLCode**, which will return html code. And it must work in IE8/9 and Firefox. I have already written a function with XMLHttpRequest, but it works only in IE8, and not in Firefox..

sample.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getHTMLCode()
{
   //... ??????
   return str;
}
</script>

</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
var pageCode=getHTMLCode("http://ip/login.aspx");
document.write(pageCode);
document.getElementsByName('LOGIN')[0].value='111'; 
document.getElementsByName('pass')[0].value='222'; 
document.getElementsByName('action')[0].focus();
document.getElementsByName('action')[0].click();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the code you already wrote and works on IE 8?

Comment: This code is: var xmlhttp = getXmlHttp()
xmlhttp.open('GET', 'url', false);
xmlhttp.send(null);
Return xmlhttp.responseText;

Comment: Your problem might be that Firefox doesn't really do asynchronous HMLHttp requests. Try instead putting your code that uses the HTML returned from the request in a function that you assign to the onload member of xmlhttp.